# Abort trap:6 Error

Tags: c

I have two functions to shift bytes for type P and other for type Q:

```
static const int vector_shift_Q_256[8] = {1,3,5,7,0,2,4,6};
static const int vector_shift_P_256[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

void shiftBytes_Q_256(uint8_t block[8][8]) {
  uint8_t block_aux[8][8];

  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if(j-(vector_shift_Q_256[i]) >= 0) 
            block_aux[i][j-(vector_shift_Q_256[i])] = block[i][j];
      else 
            block_aux[i][8+(j-(vector_shift_Q_256[i]))] = block[i][j];  
    }
  }
   memcpy(block,block_aux,L_256);
}  

void shiftBytes_P_256(uint8_t block[8][8]) {
  uint8_t block_aux[8][8];
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if(j-(vector_shift_P_256[i]) >= 0) 
            block_aux[i][j-(vector_shift_P_256[i])] = block[i][j];
        else 
            block_aux[i][8+(j-(vector_shift_P_256[i]))] = block[i][j];      
    }
  }
  memcpy(block,block_aux,L_256);
}
```

When I try to make one function for both types (P and Q) I get an error Abort trap: 6:

```
void shiftBytes_P_Q_256(uint8_t block_P[8][8],uint8_t block_Q[8][8]) {
  uint8_t block_aux_P[8][8];
  uint8_t block_aux_Q[8][8];

  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if(j-(vector_shift_P_256[i]) >= 0) {
            block_aux_P[i][j-(vector_shift_P_256[i])] = block_P[i][j];
        }if(j-(vector_shift_P_256[i]) < 0) {
            block_aux_P[i][8+(j-(vector_shift_P_256[i]))] = block_P[i][j];
        }   

        if(j-(vector_shift_Q_256[i]) >= 0) {
            block_aux_Q[i][j-(vector_shift_Q_256[i])] = block_Q[i][j];
        } if(j-(vector_shift_Q_256[i]) < 0) {
            block_aux_Q[i][8+(j-(vector_shift_Q_256[i]))] = block_Q[i][j];
        }
    }
  } 
  memcpy(block_P,block_aux_P,L_256);
  memcpy(block_Q,block_aux_Q,L_256);
}
```

I want to know why this function is causing this error.

Comment: I don't see `i` and `j` declarations..

Comment: They are declared as global variables

Comment: Not related to your question, but (1) why would you use globals as loop variables? and (2) instead of separate `if` conditions, why don't you use an `else`?